# How to remove objoct from object by finding in type script

Tags: json, typescript, object, slice, indexof

This is my object

```
 "filterValue":[
 {"label":"--Select a Member--","value":""},
 {"label":"ghi.jkl","value":{"Id":"1",}},
 {"label":"abc.def","value":{"Id":"2",}},
 {"label":"asd.vdf","value":{"Id":"3",}},
 ]
```

from this i want to search where value.Id = 2 and i want to remove that obeject line.

how can i do that..?

note:first value will be empty there is no data in value.

i have tried something like this:

```
filterValue.splice( filterValue.indexOf(2), 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use indexOf in this case because you are checking a complex object but you can use `findIndex` like this:

```
filterValue.splice( filterValue.findIndex(a => a.Id == 2), 1 );
```

You might want to change the code the check if findIndex actually found something by checking if it returns something larger than (or equal to) 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to get a new filtered array (*filteredArr*):

```js
var arr = [
   {"label":"--Select a Member--","value":""},
   {"label":"ghi.jkl","value":{"Id":"1",}},
   {"label":"abc.def","value":{"Id":"2",}},
   {"label":"asd.vdf","value":{"Id":"3",}} 
];

var filteredArr = arr.filter((x) => JSON.stringify(x.value) !== JSON.stringify({"Id":"2"}));

console.log(filteredArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of subtly traps to avoid with your specific example.

The structure of items differs, so you need to be careful that you don't have a problem with the "--Select a Member--" item, which doesn't have a `value.Id`.

The example below cheaply solves the type issue (the best common type between the array members doesn't contain the property you are interested in).

```
const items = [
    { "label": "--Select a Member--", "value": "" },
    { "label": "ghi.jkl", "value": { "Id": "1", } },
    { "label": "abc.def", "value": { "Id": "2", } },
    { "label": "asd.vdf", "value": { "Id": "3", } },
];

const filtered = items.filter((i: any) => !i.value || !i.value.Id || i.value.Id !== '2');

console.log(filtered);
```

Output:

```
[
    {"label":"--Select a Member--","value":""},
    {"label":"ghi.jkl","value":{"Id":"1"}},
    {"label":"asd.vdf","value":{"Id":"3"}}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
  filterValue: [
    { label: "--Select a Member--", value: "" },
    { label: "ghi.jkl", value: { Id: "1" } },
    { label: "abc.def", value: { Id: "2" } },
    { label: "asd.vdf", value: { Id: "3" } }
  ]
};

var changedObj = obj.filterValue.filter((data, index) => {
  return data.value.Id != "1";
});

console.log(changedObj);
```